# Unrar: Resulting files vanishing

Tags: permissions, automation, scripts, archive

Ok, so I have a directory which contains a whole load of folders containing RAR files, which I'd like to use a script to recursively unrar.

The script I have seems to work (extracting the resulting file to the directory/folder from which it's run from), however once it's finished extracting the file - it vanishes, and moves onto the next one, which vanishes also.

Regardless, the resulting un-extracted file keeps vanishing - and I have no idea why. Doesn't matter if i'm running the script with the user michaelh, or using sudo do to it.

My thinking is this is a permissions error somewhere, but I'll be dammed if I know where. However, it might be something else too - hence the reason for asking here.

### Script

```
for f in `find /media/michaelh/grill-g/video/to_sort -wholename *.rar`  
  do     
    rar e -inul $f 
done
```

### Example of directory structure and permissions

```
michaelh@grill:/media/michaelh/grill-g/video/to_sort$ ls -als
total 421624
     8 drwxrwxrwx 132 michaelh michaelh      8192 Jul 29 10:56 .
     4 drwxrwxrwx   4 michaelh michaelh      4096 Jul 19 18:42 ..
     4 drwxrwxrwx   2 michaelh michaelh      4096 Jul 27 03:47 foldername


michaelh@grill:/media/michaelh/grill-g/video/to_sort/foldername$ ls -als
total 243556
    4 drwxrwxrwx   3 michaelh michaelh     4096 Jul 26 01:22 .
    8 drwxrwxrwx 132 michaelh michaelh     8192 Jul 29 10:58 ..
    4 -rw-rw-r--   1 michaelh michaelh     1030 Jul 26 01:22 foldername.nfo
14672 -rw-rw-r--   1 michaelh michaelh 15000000 Jul 26 01:22 foldername.r00
14672 -rw-rw-r--   1 michaelh michaelh 15000000 Jul 26 01:45 foldername.r01
14672 -rw-rw-r--   1 michaelh michaelh 15000000 Jul 26 01:38 foldername.r02
14672 -rw-rw-r--   1 michaelh michaelh 15000000 Jul 26 05:29 foldername.r03
14672 -rw-rw-r--   1 michaelh michaelh 15000000 Jul 26 01:33 foldername.r04
14672 -rw-rw-r--   1 michaelh michaelh 15000000 Jul 26 05:23 foldername.r05
14672 -rw-rw-r--   1 michaelh michaelh 15000000 Jul 26 04:50 foldername.r06
14672 -rw-rw-r--   1 michaelh michaelh 15000000 Jul 26 01:28 foldername.r07
14672 -rw-rw-r--   1 michaelh michaelh 15000000 Jul 26 01:29 foldername.r08
14672 -rw-rw-r--   1 michaelh michaelh 15000000 Jul 26 05:17 foldername.r09
14672 -rw-rw-r--   1 michaelh michaelh 15000000 Jul 26 01:28 foldername.r10
14672 -rw-rw-r--   1 michaelh michaelh 15000000 Jul 26 01:29 foldername.r11
14672 -rw-rw-r--   1 michaelh michaelh 15000000 Jul 26 01:26 foldername.r12
14672 -rw-rw-r--   1 michaelh michaelh 15000000 Jul 26 05:01 foldername.r13
14672 -rw-rw-r--   1 michaelh michaelh 15000000 Jul 26 05:12 foldername.r14
 8780 -rw-rw-r--   1 michaelh michaelh  8970889 Jul 26 01:13 foldername.r15
14672 -rw-rw-r--   1 michaelh michaelh 15000000 Jul 26 05:28 foldername.rar
    4 -rw-rw-r--   1 michaelh michaelh      969 Jul 25 22:02 foldername.sfv
```

Comment: What is the result/output of `rar e foldername.rar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by changing the arguments being passed, as found unrar after further research is notorious for causing CRC errors on multi-part files.

```
for f in `find /media/michaelh/grill-g/video/to_sort -wholename *.rar`  
  do     
    rar x -kb -inul $f 
done
```

replacing e for x -kb overcame the CRC errors, and didn't remove the files once completed.